# Concurrent transactions in firebase resulting null while reading the dataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Two apps are using same firebase database. One app i.e. **A** is writing some value using **setValue**. 2nd app i.e. **B** is trying to read some data using **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** which is realted to **A** like **A** user profile information at the same time. This is resulting in null value of datasnapshot in **B** app while reading the database. Can anyone guide me how i can avoid this situation.

Just for some clearification, **A** is writing in some other node from the one which is being accessed by **B**.

This is how i am accessing the data from **B** app.

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = MyDatabaseUtils.getUsersReference();
    usersRef.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userIdValue).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get value
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                 // Do something
            } else {
                // Show error
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(final DatabaseError databaseError) {
           // Show error
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine if i stop **A** from writing at the moment of reading in **B** app.

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of the function or class which uses `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` from app **B**?

Comment: @PatNeedham, i have updated the post.

Comment: Can you explain the exact moment / action that takes place in app **A**  which causes the `ValueEventListener` from **B** to fire its `onDataChange` function? And including a related code snippet from **A** might be helpful as well.

Comment: If you get a NullPointerException, there is also a stack trace that points exactly to the line that throws the exception. Please find the stack trace, share it in your question, and indicate the line that throws the exception.

Comment: I am not having NullPointerException. The **dataSnapshot** result is null.

Comment: when is the trigger for the retrieve data method on **B**? try to change it to `addValueEventListener` to see the exact changes

Comment: What exactly does `MyDatabaseUtils.getUsersReference()` return? Is it just a helper method for `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")`? What is a user ID in your database? Is it used like `"/users/{userIdValue}":{...}` or is it `"/users/{pushId}/userId":userIdValue`? If it's the former, you should use `usersRef.child(userIdValue)` instead of `usersRef.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userIdValue)` in your query. I have a feeling that is the problem because the snapshot would always return null if `/users/{someKeyName}/userId` is never defined.

Answer (score 2):

A simplistic fix would be to guard against `datasnapshot` from being null inside the `onDataChange` function:

```
if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0)
```

It's possible that when **A** is writing to Firebase, it is removing some attributes from `usersRef`that previously existed.

Comment: The issue is not to gaurd the app for null data, the issue is, why its returing null data.

Comment: From app **A**, what specific writes are you sending to Firebase under the users/<userIdValue> node? It could be that you're using `setValue()` which would delete data at the specified location, instead of `updateChildren()` which might be more appropriate.

Comment: **A** is writing in some other node from the one which is being accessed by **B**.